# How do i run a php script every second?

Tags: php, loops

I am currently writing a online game. Now I have to check if an event happen (checking timestamp in database) and depending on that execute some actions. I have to check for an event every second.

I wanted to use a cronjob but with cron you can run a script only every minute.

My idea was to use cron and loop 60 times in my php script. But I think this isn't the best solution.

So whats the best way to run a script every second?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/342830/cron-alternative-with-timeouts-and-second-resolution .

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726116/run-a-php-script-every-second-using-cli

Comment: cron every second? what is it that you're trying to achieve? you should tell us why would you want to do this? as for cron the smallest interval is 1 minute.

Comment: I think you're looking for the wrong solution to your problem, which seems to ask for a fundamentally different architecture than you're used to. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: OK, so what kind of events may happen? Something that needs immediate action? In that case PHP is not really a great language for the project. Or just something that the user will see the next time he contacts the server? Then there's no need to *actually* do it every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a better solution but it seems that my first idea, with clean code, is the best solution.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
$start = time();

for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
    // Do whatever you want here
    time_sleep_until($start + $i + 1);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the script so that it just repeats the code every second? This will reduce the parsing overhead and be less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run the script once, and use a loop with delay to accomplish your desired timing.
The side benefit is that this is more efficient, and you would only have to open resources (ie, databases) once.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't want this :P. No host will accept your cronjob is running every second every minute?
You can save the time it runned in a database, and the next time you run it calculate the time between both runs and do the calculations you want. every second is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_time = 0;
$start_time = microtime(true);
while($total_time < 60)
  {
        //DoSomethingHere;
    echo $total_time."\n";
    //sleep(5);
  $total_time =  microtime(true) - $start_time ;
  }
```

add this in crontab to run every minute.