# php how to doing continuously processing

Tags: process, submit

I have a form that will processing input.how to make it run continuos after i just click submit once?

I want to know the method.

say i have the code :

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="tfcari" />
<input type="submit" name="btcari" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btcari'])) {

get(..);  

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Either set a time for how long it should run or how many times.

Comment: hi @Alex is this a function? how to implement it?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847663/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-every-second the accepted answer can help you.

Comment: great, i just dont know the terms.thx @Alex

Comment: @Alex hi alex, it runs simultaneous. how to doing like this example : click submit - return value - rest - return value (again) - rest - return value (again) ...