# Stagger email sending

Tags: php, mysql, email, timeout

Programmatically speaking, what would be a simple and straightforward way of spacing out the sending of bulk email while avoiding a PHP timeout? This is for contacting a few thousand members belonging to a site.

P.S: Thinking along the terms of splitting up sends into N numbers of email addresses and having a script somehow call itself.

Comment: I would just go through a third party service.

Comment: Slighly off topic, but if this is something you plan on repeatedly, you might look at commercial solutions for sending bulk emails.  You run the risk of being marked as a spammer if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending to everyone subscribed to the site, you could do the following:

1. Add a column (if it doesn't already
   exist) on the user table, something
   like 'email_sent' and default to 1
   (for yes)
2. When you execute your email send
   trigger, update all user records
   setting the 'email_sent' flag to 0
   (for no).
3. Set up a cron job that executes a
   PHP script (or even hits your web
   server using a designated page to
   execute the script) that then
   selects the first N users that have
   'email_sent' set to 0, send them
   emails, and update the 'email_sent'
   column to 1 for each that succeeds.

If you're handling multiple mailings, you would need to join across another table that maintains the user:mailout relationship and 'email_sent' status.

Comment: A sensible solution. I'll probably add these changes in the medium term to improve the site.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be just to sleep for some seconds after every x number of emails sent:

```
$count = 0
while (foo) {
    send_email();
    if ($count++ == 100) {
        sleep(10);//sleep for 10 seconds
        $count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't avoid a PHP timeout, though. It'd probably encourage it by wasting time sleeping instead of spending it mailing.

Comment: @Marc: Not exactly true, time spent sleeping does not contribute to a script's execution time.  Of course the script will take much longer to run and I agree that there are certainly more efficient ways to accomplish the goal, but the OP asked for a simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: I might give this a try. The reason I want a simple and straightforward solution is to get something running as soon as possible. Afterwards I can have a look at improvements. Another route I'm exploring is using Ajax to call a page and send emails out by blocks of 50 emails or so.

Comment: be careful that on Windows server sleep time is counted in execution time [ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/php-does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit/740959#740959], but obviously if you use Windows server you deserve the worst ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the [sleep](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) command or manually staggered cronjobs but a better option may be looking into an established library that handles details for you: PEAR [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue)

> The Mail_Queue class puts mails in a
>   temporary container, waiting to be fed
>   to the MTA (Mail Transport Agent), and
>   sends them later (e.g. a certain
>   amount of mails every few minutes) by
>   crontab or in other way.

There are also many companies that will handle all of this for you at a price, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Going with a third party isn't an option. PEAR looks interesting. I hope it supports the PHP mail function as there isn't SMTP (disabled by the host).