# PHP Repeat XML Request if not Correct

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, file-get-contents

I am using a file_get_contents along with a new SimplexmlElement($xml) in which sometimes the XML I'm pulling has a Error sign like below.  I would like to loop the request until the error message is no more and store the XML.  I have the parse already setup. But don't know how to do the loop of file_get_contents with the SimplexmlElements. The error I get is 
< error > 
< h2 > ERROR 
< / error >

Is there a way to loop a get_file_contents until condition is met in XML then us the current XML of the one where there isn't an error?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a loop:

```
while( !is_object($xml) || $tryAgain){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://www.example.com/yourxml.xml'));
    if(is_object($xml->error)){
        $tryAgain = true;
        sleep(10);
    }else{
        $tryAgain = false;
    }
}
```

See this answer regarding sleep: [Does sleep time count for execution time limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/php-does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

(`simplexml_load_file` can also load URLs, see http://php.net/simplexml-load-file , so you don't need the `file_get_contents`)