# max_execution_time and sleep()

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does sleep time count for execution time limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

If the max execution time lower than the sleep function argument

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
sleep(35);
foo();
```

will the foo() function run?

Is it OS specific or not?

**EDIT:** thank you for your answers, and for a link to a similar question: [Does sleep time count for execution time limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

Comment: As far I know it will be run only via crontab. In the browser - doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while setting the set_time_limit or max_execution_time the duration of sleep() will be ignored in the execution time. The following illustrates:

```
<?php

  set_time_limit(20);

  while ($i<=10)
{
    echo "i=$i ";
    sleep(100);
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Output:

```
i=0 i=1 i=2 i=3 i=4 i=5 i=6 i=7 i=8 i=9 i=10.
```

Taken from http://www.drupaluser.org/php_manual/function.set-time-limit.html

i think this may help.

Comment: You really get this Output after 1000 Seconds? I had to change to sleep(1) to get your result in 10 seconds even I used set_time_limit(2);