# PHP Sleep function With While Loop

Tags: php, sleep

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 I have some issue in my script ...script give me response very well if i use die instead of sleep after echo in else condition but when i use sleep(3600) after echo in else condition it is not giving me any response ...this is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

$st_time = '12:00';

$et_time = '18:00';

$cur_time = date("H:i");

while (1) {

    if (($cur_time < $et_time) && ($cur_time > $st_time)) {
        //Enter and perform Some function
    } else {
        echo 'sleep for one hour Bye';      
        sleep(3600)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you *expecting* to happen?  `sleep(3600)` means to wait for 60 minutes; that means it'll be an hour before you get a response.  However, PHP is often configured to abort scripts that take more than a short time (30 seconds or so), so you might just get an error when that happens.

Comment: you can check this post, maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518203/max-execution-time-and-sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, sleep code in micro seceonds:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$st_time = '12:00';
$et_time = '18:00';
$cur_time = date("H:i");
while (true) {
if (($cur_time < $et_time) && ($cur_time > $st_time)) {
//Enter and perform Some function
} else {
usleep(3600);
echo 'sleep for one hour Bye';        
 }
}
```

Comment: usleep here being 3600, means 0.0036 seconds. this script going to increase cpu load a lot. you need to use sleep() instead. or use usleep(3600000000)