# PHP sleep() not working how i'd hoped in redirect

Tags: php, echo, sleep

I have a form, which on submit checks the data.
if the data is invalid, I currently have it echoing text.

I want it to echo the text then pause and redirect.

I've tryed sleep(); but that causes the page to sleep on submit, wait x amount of seconds then continues without showing the echo's

Any idea of how to get around this

Comment: You need to do that on the client side using a meta refresh or a javascript redirect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15036288/1270996 You could use output buffering, but other solutions are easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send out your error message nromally and use a meta refresh to do the redirecting after x amount of seconds:

```
<?php

// your code that determines there is an error goes here

header('Refresh: 10;url=your_page.php');

echo $errorMessage;
```

The `header()` call is identical to this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='your_page.php'">
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple (although admittedly quite old fashioned) solution would be to output a meta refresh as a means of re-directing the user after a period of time. (Five seconds in the example below.)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://dest.url/whereever/'">
```

This simply sits in the HTML head as per any other meta tag. (See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) page for more information.)