# one second intervals in loop result

Tags: php, javascript, loops, for-loop, intervals

I try to make a loop (with conditions), but I do not want to see the result instantly. I want to see the result shown with one second intervals for each row.

second 1 = row 1, second 2 = row 2 (and row 1 is still visible), second 3 = row 3 (row 1, and row 2 still there and so on..)

In the first place, the PHP script should do loop (30 rows as conditions require $i<=30) and after that, start displaying the result with one second intervals for each row. Otherwise mt_rand() make a real mess with the results.

The loop example:

```
  for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
   $roll = mt_rand(1,3);     
    if ($roll=="1") {echo "1 <br />\n";}
elseif ($roll=="2") {echo "2 <br />\n";}
  else {echo "3 <br />\n"; }
```

I try to found something really simple and functionally, no jQuery, no pointlessly long code, but simple short script. My JS skill is really low, so I want to ask you guys for help. Can you help me ?

Comment: You need to send all data to the client or use Ajax. In either case look at setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: You can use `flush();` to forcefully send data, but this doesn't always work if you're using output buffering or gzip compression.

Comment: I need something what always works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem with setTimeOut() is that when the first oneNumber() function is executed, the loop has finished, and y=31. I think that there will be a way to fix a variable value when you call setTimeOut() function, but I've not found it. 
That's the only way I found out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
         $roll = mt_rand(1,3);
            if ($roll==1) {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 1</b>';}
        elseif ($roll==2) {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 2</b>';}
          else {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 3</b>';}
                             }
    ?>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () { 

    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b1').style.display="block";
    },1000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b2').style.display="block";
    },2000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b3').style.display="block";
    },3000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b4').style.display="block";
    },4000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b5').style.display="block";
    },5000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b6').style.display="block";
    },6000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b7').style.display="block";
    },7000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b8').style.display="block";
    },8000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b9').style.display="block";
    },9000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b10').style.display="block";
    },10000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b11').style.display="block";
    },11000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b12').style.display="block";
    },12000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b13').style.display="block";
    },13000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b14').style.display="block";
    },14000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b15').style.display="block";
    },15000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b16').style.display="block";
    },16000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b17').style.display="block";
    },17000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b18').style.display="block";
    },18000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b19').style.display="block";
    },19000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b20').style.display="block";
    },20000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b21').style.display="block";
    },21000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b22').style.display="block";
    },22000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b23').style.display="block";
    },23000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b24').style.display="block";
    },24000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b25').style.display="block";
    },25000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b26').style.display="block";
    },26000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b27').style.display="block";
    },27000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b28').style.display="block";
    },28000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b29').style.display="block";
    },29000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('b30').style.display="block";
    },30000)
    }   

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: wow, this really works, it's a little complicated, but working.. I play with that, maybe I find something simpler. THX.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function? takes seconds to wait before executing next statement. Also changed your 1-2-3 logic, condition does not seem necessary.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
   $roll = mt_rand(1,3);
   sleep(1);
   echo $roll." <br />";
}
```

Comment: the loop is only example, so don't bother with logic.. sleep() make a long time delay before page is reload.. so no, it's not the function what I'm looking for.. I need every 1 second be displayed 1 row of total 30 rows..

Comment: actually, in the end of the day, the sleep() was the function what I'm looking for, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause your PHP for one second after each row and flush the output buffer each time it wakes up:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
    $roll = mt_rand(1,3);     
    if ($roll == "1")
        echo "1 <br />\n";
    else if ($roll == "2")
        echo "2 <br />\n";
    else
        echo "3 <br />\n";

    // Flush the output buffer
    ob_flush();
    // Sleep for one second
    sleep(1);
}
```

It is necessary to call `ob_flush()` because PHP buffers output, so simply sleeping will delay the page output, but it will still appear at once in the browser.

When you do this, please be aware that your script execution time may be longer than the maximum execution time allowed by PHP.
You can set this limit in your code:

```
set_time_limit(90); // Maximum execution time is 90 seconds
set_time_limit(0);  // No execution time limit
```

or in your php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 90
```

Comment: nope, long time for reloading page.. I need every 1 second be displayed 1 row of total 30 rows..

Comment: Calling ob_flush() will send each row to the browser even if the page is not finished loading, even if your page takes ages to load.

Comment: yes, I tried to and take error -> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded, I don't want to wait for result and then see it immediately, I want see every 1 second another row of total 30 rows.. so, after 30 seconds, the 30 rows will be displayed.

Comment: this works for me fine and it's similarly to your advice -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036232/php-loop-how-to-print-each-result-and-delay-it-for-a-second-before-echoing-anot

Answer (score 0):

I'd use setTimeout() function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: always use authentic and up to date references. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: I'll try to make every row in loop a ID and set display: none; then JS, something like that (but no luck): <script>
 
function oneNumber () {
     document.getElementById('b'+y.toString()).style.display="block";
}
 
var y=1;
 
while(y<31) {
   window.setTimeout("oneNumber()",1*1000);
y=y+1;
 
}</script>

Comment: leave quotes inside setTimeout() function.

Comment: Try this: <script> function oneNumber (y) { document.getElementById('b'+y).style.display="block"; } var y=1; while(y<31) { window.setTimeout(oneNumber(y),1*1000); y=y+1; }</script>

Comment: nothing happend.. I was trying your script with this PHP code -> <?php
for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
     $roll = mt_rand(1,3);
        if ($roll=="1") {echo "<b id=b".$i." style='display: none';> 1</b>\n";}
    elseif ($roll=="2") {echo "<b id=b".$i." style='display: none';> 2</b>\n";}
      else {echo "<b id=b".$i." style='display: none';> 3</b>\n";}
                         }
?>

Comment: You forgot quotes. Copy the next: <?php for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) { $roll = mt_rand(1,3); if ($roll=="1") {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 1</b>\n';} elseif ($roll=="2") {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 2</b>\n';} else {echo '<b id="b'.$i.'" style="display: none;"> 3</b>\n';} } ?>

Comment: And $roll=="1", $roll=="2", should be $roll==1 and $roll==2

Comment: What is happening? Are your tags displayed with display:none? Any tag is been displayed with javascript? Does the browser debugger display any errors? Have you tried any console.log() to see some variables? without in any way detracting from the other valuable opinions, I think JS is the most simply way to do what you want to do.

Comment: what happening ? instantly show all numbers, display is still none, simply JS is completelly ignore.. you can see for yourself, if you test this scripts on your own.. all scripts are here, I don't know, what is wrong, but it's in JS, that's for sure and JS is complicated for me, that's why I was asking for help..

Comment: For your information (if you don't know yet), if you are using Firefox, you can install Firebug from the browser's tools. Then, if you type "console.log('variable = '+variable)" in your JS code (replacing variable with your variable), you can see the value of one or more variables in the firebug console. It's like the "echo" of PHP.

Comment: I'm using chrome, and I'm testing JS in online error logs, but it doesn't matter.. Even if the JS error log found no errors, the script is completly ignore, and nothing happened. PHP make the work, but JS not.

Comment: It occurred to me that it could be due to: a) The url to the JS script is not right. Check it. b) JS is disabled in chrome (in configuration -> Advanced options -> content configuration -> enable javascript).

Comment: Also try this: window.onload = function ()
{
Javascript code goes here
}

Comment: JS is enabled and in place with PHP in the same file. it's only 1 file.. pls, try it yourself, here's the content of the file, maybe this is the way, how you can find, what is wrong -> http://efai.wz.cz/loop.rar