# Javascript to display PHP value with one second delay

Tags: javascript, php, delay

I have something like this

```
<?php 
    for ($x=0; $x<10; $x++) {

        echo $x;
}
?>
```

Now i need to display that $x data one after another with one second delay; i believe i need javascript to do that.

I've found various of similar scripts, but none worked for me, can anyone post any example on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there may be some confusion. PHP is ***server-side*** and JavaScript is ***client-side***. By the time the JavaScript begins to execute, the PHP has already completed it's execution. The only way to accomplish something like this is with AJAX.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: wow, you need to stop what you're doing right now and readup on backend vs front end

Comment: is it possible in any way to delay the output of for loop for one second and display it one after another?

Comment: @skymario84 No. Again, you're talking server-side vs client-side. You can delay the PHP execution by 1 second intervals. All that is going to do though is delay the output and probably show a blank white page until the script finishes execution. The user will still see the completed output from the script execution (i.e. All numbers, not one at a time).

Comment: @War10ck well, technically its prob possible with a websocket or something, but @@skymario84 it would be better to send all the data to the browser in one hit, probably in a json encoded array, then loop through in javascript

Comment: @andrew thanks, i wanted to do something like that, but can't get it to work, can you post any examples on how to do that?

Comment: @andrew That's true. Very good point.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036232/php-loop-how-to-print-each-result-and-delay-it-for-a-second-before-echoing-anot?rq=1[link] @Rich's answer solved it all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need JavaScript for this.  All PHP can do is emit the values to client-side code.  Then it's up to the client-side code to display those values.

So, for example, your PHP code can populate a JavaScript array:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
    var values = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>;
</script>
```

In this case `$php_variable` would be an array containing the values you want to display.  Now your client-side code has an array called `values` which it can iterate.  You can use `setTimeout` to schedule something to happen with a delay.  Iterating over that array, it might look something like this:

```
var index = 0;
var displayValue = function () {
    if (index >= values.length) { return; }

    var value = values[index++];
    // display "value" somewhere on your page

    setTimeout(displayValue, 1000);
};
displayValue();
```

This should display each value in the array with 1-second increments.  Note that I sort of glazed over the "display somewhere on your page" part, since that's up to you really.  Where/how are you looking to display this?  This works a little differently client-side than it does server-side, since the entire HTML document is already rendered.  You need to identify where in that document you want to display the value and display it there, not just "echo" it.