# Php max_execution_time ignored

Tags: php, timeout

Hi i'm trying to stop long running php scripts

so i've created this scrtipt for testing

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time',1);
set_time_limit(1);

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        echo time();
        echo '    i:' . $i;
        echo '<br/>';
        sleep(2);
}
phpinfo();
```

the php info outputs

```
Directive           Local Value  Master Value
max_execution_time  1            30
```

but the script is not aborted after 1 sec. Why?

Comment: Are you under a shared hosting ? Most of the times you wouldn't be able to edit such configuration in such environment.

Comment: no it's my own root server, PHP Version 5.3.8

Comment: does this example work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep Time doesn't count towards max_execution_time or in other words:
Sleep Time doesn't count as execution time.

See: [Does sleep time count for execution time limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

Comment: can you provide a link to the according documentation?

Comment: I can't because It isn't documented, but I put a link to another question.
It is also mentioned in the comments of the documentation:
http://ch1.php.net/sleep

Answer (score 0):

This is a [PHP Bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49868&edit=1)  which should have been fixed in  5.3.1 . [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) overrides [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: i have PHP Version 5.3.8, and max_input_time is not set after max_execution_time