# Why the script does NOT show "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XX seconds"?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I would like to know why php (I'm using 5.5) doesn't stop this script with a fatal error. Thanks.

```
<?
set_time_limit(5);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
echo 'hi';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    sleep(1);
}
echo '<br>bye';
?>
```

The output of the script is:

```
hi<br>bye
```

Without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Because sleeping doesn't take up any execution time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does sleep time count for execution time limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes):

> The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration directive `max_execution_time` only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

To paraphrase this documentation answer, it basically means that `sleep()` is not a time consuming function in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep();` on linux is not count by the max execution time, see the user contribution [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and the answer on the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

Comment: Edit to the other answers, safe mode is deprecated and **removed** from PHP 5.4.0