# Apache hangs after 200 seconds not receiving output

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

I have a PHP script that hangs in the browser when it runs for over 200 seconds. This PHP script calls `shell_exec` on a bash script and waits for output. Then, echoes that output to the browser.

**Everything works fine when:**

- script runs < 200 seconds
- run script from command line as localuser NOT apache

**Does not work when:**

- run from the browser (apache)
- run for > 200 seconds

The operations of the bash script execute fine in all cases and i can see the output when i write it to the console ... but it will just hang in the browser (no output) even after the script has "finished".

I understand that `set_time_limit` will not have an effect here because system commands do not count towards script execution time.

**REF:** [Max Execution Time and System Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740954/does-sleep-time-count-for-execution-time-limit)

---

Below is a screenshot of my Apache timeout settings. To be honest, I am unsure if that would contribute to this issue, if using `shell_exec` (thus not outputting / echoing anything for some time) would have an effect on that, or what would result if an Apache timeout were to occur.

[image: Apache Timeout Settings]

---

**OTHER NOTES**

I think it could be worth noting that after some time of leaving the script "hanging", it runs again without prompting.

Comment: check your apache timeout settings

Comment: @delboy1978uk I uploaded a screenshot of my apache timeout settings and also added a note to the question in regards to that.

Comment: If Apache gives up before PHP, that'll be your problem

Comment: Would that cause the "browser" to just keep "spinning"?

Comment: Could be worth nothing that after some time of leaving the script hanging ... it runs again without prompting.